# Error: Target container is not a DOM element. - with out of the box app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just starting to learn React. I used Create-React to generate a basic app.

App.js

```
import  React  from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (<div>Hi There!</div>);
};

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM   from 'react-dom';
import App  from './components/App';
console.log(document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render((<App/> , document.getElementById('root')));
```

I get an error

> Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

[image]

Code Link : https://github.com/rberger247/ReactApp/blob/master/client/src/components/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need correct ReactDOM.render like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```